# How to create bookmarks -table of contents- from headings with iText?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I create pdf from a list of html codes. it generates pdf very well. But I want to add table of contents to the pdf. Table of contents should be created from h1, h2 etc. How can I do it? Below is my function to create pdf. I looked to existing examples in iText site but I couldn't make it work as I want it.

```
public static void createMultiplePagedPdf(String destinationFile, ArrayList<String> htmlStrings,
        String cssLocation, HeaderFooter headerFooter, boolean tableOfContents) {

    String css = null;
    ElementList list = null;
    Document document = new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));
        if(headerFooter!=null)
            writer.setPageEvent(headerFooter);
        TableOfContent tocEvent = new TableOfContent();
        writer.setPageEvent(tocEvent);
        document.open();

        if(tableOfContents){
             tocEvent.setRoot(writer.getRootOutline());
             for (TOCEntry entry : tocEvent.getToc()) {
                    Chunk c = new Chunk(entry.title);
                    c.setAction(entry.action);
                    document.add(new Paragraph(c));
                }
        }

        if (cssLocation != null)
            css = readCSS(cssLocation);

        for (String htmlfile : htmlStrings) {
            if (css != null)
                list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(htmlfile, css);
            else
                list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(htmlfile, null);
            for (Element e : list) {
                document.add(e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Pdf Created successfully");
        document.close();
    } catch ...
}
```

`tocEvent.getToc()` returns an empty list. When I move that if statement to the end of code it doesn't matter.
My TOCEntry and TableOfContent classes are the same as written in the first example of [Creating Table of Contents using events](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples-itext5/creating-table-contents-using-events) Using iText5. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `TableOfContent`? Is it a copy of the `TOCEvent` class? If so, that class expects generic tags in `Chunk` objects. You don't have such tags, so it is normal that `tocEvent.getToc()` returns an empty list. Also: is there a specific reason why you convert the HTML to an `ElementList`? If you convert the HTML straight to PDF, then you automatically have bookmarks.

Comment: OK, on second inspection of your code, I see that you are actually parsing different HTML files into one PDF file. Once the HTML is converted to PDF, the elements don't know about the original tags anymore (an `<h>` tag results in a `Paragraph`). which explains why the default creation of bookmarks doesn't work.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie yes it is a copy of TOCEvent class.
The html's are containing only div, h1 and p tags. In the pdf h1's saved as bookmarks however I couldn't create table of contents.